# PSQL - Performance of query filtered by intervals on two separate fields

Tags: postgresql, indexing, intervals

I have got a PostgreSQL table that covers time intervals.

This is a simplified structure of my table

```
CREATE TABLE intervals (
  name        varchar(40),
  time_from   timestamp,
  time_to     timestamp
);
```

The table contains millions of records, but, if you apply a filter in a specific point of time in the past, the number of records for which

```
time_from <= [requested time] <= time_to
```

are always very limited in number (not more than 3k results). So, a query like this one

```
SELECT *
FROM intervals
WHERE time_from <= '2020-01-01T10:00:00' and time_to >= '2020-01-01T10:00:00'
```

is supposed to return a relatively small amount of results, and, in theory, it should be quite fast if I used the correct index. But it's not fast at all

I tried adding a combined index on time_from and time_to, but the engine doesn't pick it.

```
Seq Scan on intervals  (cost=0.00..156152.46 rows=428312 width=32) (actual time=13.223..3599.840 rows=4981 loops=1)
  Filter: ((time_from <= '2020-01-01T10:00:00') AND (time_to >= '2020-01-01T10:00:00'))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 2089650
    Planning Time: 0.159 ms
    Execution Time: 3600.618 ms
```

What type of index should I add, in order to speed up this query?

Comment: Do you have an index on `(time_from, time_to)` The optimizer completely over estimates the number of rows. Does running `analyze intervals` (or `vacuum analyze intervals;`) change anything?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I ran vacuum analyze. It returns nothing, and after running it the number of estimated rows is still in the order of the 400k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A btree index cannot be very efficient here.  It can quickly throw out everything whose time_from > '2020-01-01T10:00:00', but that is probably not all that much of the table (at least, not if your table goes back for many years).  Once the first column of the index has been consumed in this way, the next column cannot be used very efficiently.  It can only jump to a specific part of time_to values within the ties of time_from, and that is just not very useful as there are probably not all that many ties.  (At least, not that it can prove to itself while planning your query).

What you need is a gist index, which specializes in this kind of multi-dimensional thing:

```
create extension btree_gist ;
create index on intervals using gist (time_from,time_to);
```

This index will support your query as written.  Another possibility is to index the time ranges and index those, rather than separate begin and end point.

```
-- this one does not need btree_gist.
create index on intervals using gist (tsrange(time_from,time_to));
```

But this index forces you to write the query differently:

```
SELECT * FROM intervals
WHERE tsrange(time_from,time_to) @> '2020-01-01T10:00:00'::timestamp
```

Comment: The second index you proposed worked perfectly! Thanks! I always felt there must be a straightforward way to optimise this